# Migration of votes

Tags: discussion, migration, down-votes

When a question is migrated to another site, any upvotes are transferred with it and are credited on the target site.

Questions that are off-topic here often receive downvotes simply because they're off-topic; they may be good quality questions on the target site.  When the question is migrated, do any downvotes also get migrated (that would seem like starting with a penalty and a visual bias on the new site)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Do any downvotes also get migrated?

No:

> As [Jon has suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/31091/267099)<sup>1</sup>, a migrated question with a negative score will now be reset to 0.

Source meta.se [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52586/267099) by [Jarrod Dixon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/3/jarrod-dixon)

<sup>1 This is the first time I've managed to legitimately sneak in a reference to Jon Skeet in an answer :)</sup>

Comment: Your answer, and the one you link to, are ambiguous; to the extent that meaning can be ascribed to them, they are contradictory.   Consider a question with three upvotes and seven downvotes.   [Jarrod Dixon’s answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31088/195817#52586) suggests that such a question would have its score reset to 0.   But that can be interpreted as meaning that three upvotes and three downvotes got migrated, while you say that they don’t.   @fixer1234’s implicit suggestion is that such questions should have a score of +3 after migration.

Comment: @Scott, I wasn't really suggesting a specific solution, just was curious how it's done.  My main concern was starting on a new site with a negative net score, which would bias reception there.  We don't know that all downvotes were for being off-topic, so we also don't want to encourage people to post low quality questions on the wrong site to get a free pass on legit downvotes.  The current process seems like a good compromise.

Comment: @Scott I agree this statement is ambiguous while the mentioned Jon’s suggestion is not. You should copy your comment to the [original post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52586/217657).